# How do I upgrade a MDL table from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I want to: Generate a table that has tickboxes.

I generate a table's code from JS, then I change the innerHTML of a parent node to include it.

If I call `componentHandler.upgradeElement` on the , I get this: [image: Called upgradeElement on the <table>]

As you can see, there is also the order messed up!

If I call `componentHandler.upgradeElement` on nothing, this happens: [image]

How do I upgrade the whole table? The table has mdl-data-table--selectable class...

The performance is not absolutely crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling upgradeDom?

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

Answer (score 0):

mdl-data-table--selectable seems to be deprecated.

[From the Material Design Lite site:](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations)

> There are numerous issues with the implementation and adding in
>   support to handle these problems will only add a good portion of
>   complexity to a component that is otherwise very simple. If you are
>   currently using mdl-data-table--selectable then this will affect you.
>   The recommended alternative is for developers to create the checkboxes
>   on their own.

This solved the issue of disappearing checkboxes at least for me. Be aware that you have to implement the "select all" functionality manually.